# libmysqlclient_r.a not getting generated

Tags: mysql, database, linux, cmake, mysql-connector

I have downloaded mysql-connector-c-6.0.2. I build it using below commands:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install_dir_path>
make
make install
```

This creates below library files:

```
libmysqlclient.a  libmysqlclient_r.so  libmysqlclient.so  libmysql.so  libmysql.so.16  libmysql.so.16.0.0
```

This does not generate libmysqlclient_r.a. How do I enable generation of libmysqlclient_r.a?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Update:**

libmysqlclient_r.so is actually a symbolic link to libmysql.so (libmysqlclient_r.so and libmysqlclient.so are both symbolic links to libmysql.so. So they are both same). A static library (libmysql.a) can be produced by removing the SHARED keyword from the following line in libmysql/CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(libmysql          SHARED ${CLIENT_SOURCES} libmysql.def)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not generated, then it's done by intent by developers.

Check some build options, maybe there is option to enable static build of `libmysqlclient_r`. If not - you have to find its target declaration in one of `CMakeLists.txt` and adjust it to enable static build.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was really helpful. I really appreciate it.